# Examples website with payload of all magento 2 rest api

Tags: rest-api

Hello a few weeks ago here I saw a website that contained all the payloads of the magento 2 rest api but now I can't find it please can you pass it to me.?

I am looking for the payload of this api:

```
POST   /V1/products/options
PUT    /V1/products/options/:optionId
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find the REST API documentation here https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/.

The endpoints you are looking for are these: https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/catalogProductCustomOptionRepositoryV1

Comment: thanks is what i need